# Android build always creates the debug apk

Tags: android, build, codenameone

I have got the problem, that the Android-build in Codenameone always creates the debug version - and I don't know how to create the release version.
I set the build hints in this way:
android.debug=false
android.release=true

(see attached Screenshot from Eclipse).

What can I do to build the release-version?

Kind regards
Klaus[image]

Comment: What are you building with?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved now - but I don't know exactly, what action leads to the solution. What I did:

- I set both android.release and android.debug to true
- I refreshed the path to the certificate because I moved the directory so the old path leads to a not existing key-file
- I also used the codenameone setting-pages to toggle release/debug - not the eclipse configuration page.

After this actions I tried another build - and got the debug AND release-version as result.

Comment: The reason this happens is if you send a build without a certificate. Once you create a certificate this will build a release version by default without you changing anything.